# Почему не работает автозаполнение в мультиселекте?

Tags: django, django-filter

Нужно чтобы в мультиселекте выбирались автоматически значения, но это почему-то не происходит. Пробовал определять `initial` в `forms.py`

**models**

```
class Provider(models.Model):
    payment = models.ManyToManyField(Payment, related_name="provider", blank=True)
    delivery = models.ManyToManyField(Delivery, related_name="provider", blank=True)
```

**forms**

```
class ProductCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'payment_method': forms.SelectMultiple(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'select2',
                    'style': 'width: 335px',
                    'onchange': 'checkProductMethod(event, this);'
                }
            ),

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('initial').get('request')
        super(ProductCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        provider = Provider.objects.filter(user=self.request.user.id).last())
        self.fields['payment_method'] = ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=provider.payment.all())
        print([i for i in provider.payment.all().values_list('id', flat=True)])    #Список значений
        self.fields['payment_method'].initial = [i for i in provider.payment.all().values_list('id', flat=True)]
```

**views**

```
class ProductsCreate(CreateView):
    model = Product
    form_class = ProductCreateForm
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post']

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(ProductsCreate, self).get_initial()
        initial['request'] = self.request
        return initial

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ctx=super(ProductsCreate, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        ctx['special_form'] = SpeciallyPriceForm()
        return ctx

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        if kwargs.get('slug'):
            category = Category.objects.filter(slug=kwargs.get('slug')).first()
            self.initial.update({'category': category})
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Варианты решения

```
self.fields['payment_method'].initial = [i for i in provider.payment.all().values_list('pk', flat=True)]
```

А можно и вовсе без `values_list`.

```
self.fields['payment_method'].initial = [i.pk for i in provider.payment.all()]
```

Ну либо же таким образом

```
self.initial['payment_method'] = [i.pk for i in provider.payment.all()]
```

Или же всё аналогично, то вместо `pk` - `id`.

Comment: `self.fields['payment_method'].initial = [i.id for i in provider.payment.all()]` - так тоже не работает?

Comment: @Александр сейчас работает. Чертовщина какая-то. Хотя я уже догадываюсь, в чём была проблема

Answer (score 0):

Вместо `flat=True` лучше использовать `named=True`, либо вообще ничего не использовать, потому что flat нужен, если в модели только одно поле, поэтому может быть ошибка отображения

Comment: `Unexpected keyword arguments to values_list: ['named']` Вроде, `flat` используется для списков, в моделях с несколькими полями.. Вот нашёл подобный вопрос, но у меня не проходят эти решения, как видите https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26966527/django-modelmultiplechoicefield-set-initial-values

Comment: Действительно, забыл, что values_list возвращает список, named здесь точно не подходит, мои извинения

Comment: Разобрался уже, кстати.